# Function always returns pointer to null

Tags: c, pointers

Why does `createArray` function returns pointer to 0? 
I guess, that i should use malloc to fix it, but why?

```
   int *createArray(int size)
{
    int i;
    int arr[size];

    i = 0;
    while (i < size)
    {
        arr[i] = i;
        i++;
    }
    return arr;
}

int main()
{
    int *ar;
    printf("%i", (createArray(10)));
}
```

Comment: you return local array and it's undefined behavior. lifetime of this array only in function scope, when you return from function array doesn't exist anymore

Comment: The variable `arr` is local inside the `createArray` function, when the function returns the life-time of `arr` ends and the pointer to its first element will become invalid immediately.

Comment: Pretty sure that compiler given lot of good readable warnings, but seems you ignored them.  For e.g 1. _function returns address of local variable ? 2. _‘%i’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’_

Comment: @Achal: You don't know which compiler he's using. gcc gives those warnings. Other compilers are likely to as well, but it's not guaranteed.

Comment: @Achal clang has told me nothing :(

Comment: You are right, you need to malloc(size* sizeof(int)). you are making a local array, when the function is called the memory on the stack from this point on is allocated for it *until* you return from that function. the stack returns to its prior state and all the functions local values can not be reached. when you use malloc- you are asking for memory allocation in the heap- this is done by the OS, and you must remember to free it once it is no longer needed

Comment: True @KeithThompson but it's not a recommended practice. @Vladimir compile with `Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wpedantic`.

Comment: @Vladimir clang gave me "warning: address of stack memory associated with local variable 'arr' returned [-Wreturn-stack-address]".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you return an array from a function, you're actually returning a pointer to the first element of the array.  And when a function returns, the memory used by its local variables are no longer valid.

So you're returning a pointer to a variable that no longer exists.  Using that pointer in any way invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).  In this particular case, the invalid address is able to be dereferenced and happens to contain the value 0, however there's no guarantee that behavior will be consistent when you make changes to your program.

For this to work, you need to dynamically allocate memory.  Then it can be used though the lifetime of the program.

```
int *arr = malloc(sizeof(*arr) * size);
```

This also means you'll need to `free` this memory when you're done using it:

```
int *ar = createArray(10);
printf("%i", ar[0]);
free(ar);
```

Answer (score 1):

arr variable is allocated on the stack.
When returning from your function the stack is freed.
The pointer you are returning will then point to an invalid memory location that may be set to null.

Answer (score 1):

The basic problem is that your function is returning the address of a local variable. That local variable no longer exists once the function returns, so any pointer to it is invalid.

To correct some of the problems with your code, I added `#include <stdio.h>` to the top (required for `printf`) and changed your `printf` call from

```
printf("%i", (createArray(10)));
```

to

```
printf("%p\n", (void*)createArray(10));
```

When I compile with gcc and run the program, the output is:

```
(nil)
```

meaning that your function is returning a null pointer.  (It's not a "pointer to null"; the pointer *is* null.)  That's not what I would have expected; I expected a invalid garbage pointer value. (When I use tcc rather than gcc, I get `0x7fffd95a7140`.)

Apparently gcc recognizes that your code has undefined behavior, and replaces the `return` statement with the equivalent of `return NULL;`.  This is a perfectly legitimate transformation (and it might prevent your program from doing something nasty with the invalid pointer, modifying memory that your program doesn't own).

Bottom line: Your program has undefined behavior, and you can't assume anything about what it will do. And yes, allocating an array using `malloc` and returning the address of the allocated array is one way to fix it.